# How do i change logback version in spring boot?

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot

I want to use logback smtp appender in my spring boot application, but somehow  spring boot default logback 1.1.7 dependency does not work well with SMTP appenders. How can I downgrade spring boot provided logback library from 1.1.7 to 1.1.6? I am using gradle for build management.

Update

It worked after i tried Andy's Answer, so now my build.gradle file looks like this

```
buildscript {
...    
 ext['logback.version'] = '1.1.6'
 ...
}
```

Comment: Please share the `build.gradle`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your best bet is to override the `logback.version` property. This will ensure that you get the desired version of Logback everywhere:

```
ext['logback.version'] = '1.1.6'
```